# How far (distance) can Minecraft spiders jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am not looking for how high (Y) a spider can jump.  I am looking for how far (X or Z) a spider can jump.

Let's say I have a spider sitting on a edge.  How many blocks apart does the opposite edge need to be so that the spider can't jump and land on it?

```
spider
XXXXXX<- distance ->XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Minecraft 1.18.1 in Survival Mode, I setup a covered platform 50 blocks up.  I then slowly increased the X horizontal gap.

If the gap is ≤ 3 blocks, then the spiders will jump and land on top of the blocks and attack the player.

If the gap is 4 blocks, then the spiders will jump and grab onto the side the blocks.  If the spider is determined, it will climb up and attack the player; otherwise, it seems to let go of the side of the block and falls.

Answer (score 0):

Spiders can jump up to 3 blocks on the x-y axis

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While this technically answers part of the question it would be preferable to include a reputable source of this answer so it doesn't seem like you just made the number up. Also note that the question is about the direction on the X/Z horizontal plane.

Comment: Do you mean `x-z` axis?